# Переписать FBV на CBV Django

Tags: python, django, django-model, django-view

Как переписать представление с FBV на CBV?

```
@login_required
def add_to_wishlist(request, id):
product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=id)
if product.users_wishlist.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
    product.users_wishlist.remove(request.user)
    messages.success(request, product.title + " has been removed from your WishList")
else:
        product.users_wishlist.add(request.user)
    messages.success(request, "Added " + product.title + " to your WishList")
return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META["HTTP_REFERER"])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class MyView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def get(self, request, id):
        product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=id)
        if product.users_wishlist.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
            product.users_wishlist.remove(request.user)
            messages.success(request, product.title + " has been removed from your WishList")
        else:
            product.users_wishlist.add(request.user)
            messages.success(request, "Added " + product.title + " to your WishList")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META["HTTP_REFERER"])
```

Comment: а когда перегрузка метода get нужно вызывать super?

Comment: нет, есть метод dispatch, он заранее определен и всего лишь вызывает метод в зависимости от используемого метода запроса https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/views/generic/base.py